# How to download the edited dataframe in .csv format in rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing an Rshiny application in which I edited the contents of the dataframe and downloading the edited dataframe in .csv format. But the downloaded file is not in .csv format. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(filename = function() {paste(Sys.time(), 'Edited Table.csv', sep='') } ,content = function(file) {write.csv(sample_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)})
```

This is the code used. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your results with an example, but I couldn't reproduce your issue. Here is a self-sufficient RShiny App which downloads a .csv file. Make sure your app follows this template, if the issue still persists please provide a reproducible example of the same.

```
library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {

    # Your Sample dataset
    sample_data <- reactive({mtcars})

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste(Sys.time(), ' Edited Table.csv', sep='')
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(sample_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: By using the above code it downloads the dataframe in a .file format and it can be viewed using either Notepad, Word etc. But I need to download it in .csv format. Is it clear?

Comment: I don't think the issue has got anything to do with the code. Make sure you have Microsoft Excel installed and also make the default program for opening files as MS Excel for files with .xlsx,.xlsx,.csv extensions. Here is a link for your reference on how to setup default options in windows [Default Program Setting](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-change-file-associations/)